# Macro for configuring directory locations

Tags: macros, document-classes

I'm trying to understand how class files work. In the example I am working with, it is from [awesome-cv](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) template file. In the .cls file there is a part where a macro is defined for setting directory for fonts.

```
\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}
```

What I would like to understand specifically is what does `\@fontdir` do in this context? It seems like a primitive command but I couldn't find it in any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not do anything, the command you show just saves the supplied argument in the macro `\@fontdir` which is just an arbitrary name presumably elsewhere in the package code that is used.

This idiom is quite common in latex, for example it is exactly the same as `\title` in the standard classes (apart from the default value)

If you go

```
\title{hello world}
```

then that just does

```
\def\@title{hello world}
```

to save that string, and nothing happens unless some macro (`\maketitle` in this case) uses `\@title` somewhere.

So here you can go

```
\fontdir{a/b/c}
```

but it is exactly the same as going

```
\renewcommand\@fontdir{a/b/c}
```

and does nothing unless `\@fontdir` is used.

Looking at the class source it later does

```
\newfontfamily\FA[Path=\@fontdir]{FontAwesome}
```

which means that if you have installed the matching font in a non-standard place you can record the folder where it is using the `\fontdir` command which will save that location in `\@fontdir` and it will get used in the above font loading command. So it is just specific to this one font, loaded by this class, not a general mechanism.